# To get output of movie with its genre

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am writing a program to get an output of movies with there genre.

```
sample database

Movie        movie_id , title (1, snitch)
genre        genre_id , genre (1, Action)(2, Animation)(3, Drama)(4, Crime )
movie_genre  movie_id, genre_id (1,1)(1,3)(1,4)
```

this is my code

```
  <?php 
  $stmt = $pdo->query("
  SELECT * 
   FROM movie, genre, movie_genre WHERE movie.movie_id = 
   movie_genre.movie_id AND genre.genre_id = movie_genre.genre_id And 
   movie.name='snitch'
  ");
   while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){

   $title= $row['title'];
   $genre= $row['genre'];
   ?>
        <h1> <?php echo $title ; ?> </h1>
            <h1> <?php echo $genre ; ?> </h1>

    <?php } ?>
```

the output I am getting is "
Snitch
Action
Snitch
Drama
Snitch
Crime "

but I want "
Snitch
Action
Drama
Crime "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $row contains the title ("Snitch") and ONE genre.  You loop through this, so it's echoing the title with each row.  Try this replacement:

```
   $oldtitle = $title = '';
   while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){

   $title= $row['title'];
   if ( $oldtitle == $title ) $title = '';
   else  $oldtitle = $title;

   $genre= $row['genre'];
   ?>
        <h1> <?php echo $title ; ?> </h1>
            <h1> <?php echo $genre ; ?> </h1>

   <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the select part you didn't mention any fields. You can right in 2 way.

```
SELECT movie.movie_id , movie.title , genre.genre
FROM movie, genre, movie_genre WHERE movie.movie_id = 
movie_genre.movie_id AND genre.genre_id = movie_genre.genre_id And 
movie.name='snitch'
```

OR

```
SELECT movie.movie_id , movie.title , genre.genre
FROM movie 
INNER JOIN movie_genre ON movie.movie_id = movie_genre.movie_id
INNER JOIN genre ON genre.genre_id = movie_genre.genre_id 
WHERE movie.name='snitch'
```

Comment: No, i didn't like it too. i just use his code and fixed select part in option one

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing the title *and* genre in each iteration of the loop. Since you are interested in one title in particular, a possible solution is just to extract the genre from the result:

```
$title = 'snitch';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM movie, genre, movie_genre 
    WHERE movie.movie_id = movie_genre.movie_id 
    AND genre.genre_id = movie_genre.genre_id AND movie.title = :title");

$stmt->execute([':title' => $title]);
$genre = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $genre[] = $row['genre'];
}

echo $title . ': ' . implode(', ', $genre);
```

For multiple titles you can follow a similar strategy:

```
$movie_genres = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  // If this movie isn't in the result yet...
  if (!isset($movie_genres[$row['title']])) {
      $movie_genres[$row['title']] = [];
  }
  // Add the genre
  $movie_genres[$row['title']][] = $row['genre'];
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Rmct2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDO's constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) and method [`fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). Try `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`. It will group all results in the query by the first column. In this case I am fetching only 2 columns `title` and `genre`. The result is:

```
Array ( 
    [snitch] => Array ( 
        [0] => Action 
        [1] => Drama 
        [2] => Crime 
    ) 
)
```

I mixed it with `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` to get only a single column in my sub-array, but you do not need to do that and you can get the whole array.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT title, genre
    FROM movie, genre, movie_genre 
    WHERE movie.movie_id = movie_genre.movie_id 
        AND genre.genre_id = movie_genre.genre_id 
        And movie.title='snitch'
");
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP|\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
foreach($data as $title => $genres){
    echo '<h1>'.$title.'</h1>';
    foreach($genres as $genre){
        echo '<h2>'.$genre.'</h2>';
    }
}
```